# Using the -D name compilation option from a shell script

Tags: c++, shell, compilation, macros

I'm attempting to write a shell script that will run several tests of my C++ program, redefining a macro each time it runs. I'm trying to use the -D *name* preprocessor option (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), but I'm consistently getting the warning that the macro is being redefined, and then the program executes without redefining it.

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#NUMS is number of subdivisions:
for subdiv in 10 100 500 1000
do
    echo NUMS = $subdiv
    g++ -D NUMS=$subdiv project01.cpp -o project01 -lm -fopenmp
    ./project01 >> bezier_results.txt
done
```

In my C++ file, project01.cpp, I state:

```
#define NUMS 1
```

I've tried leaving out the '1', but that produces errors as well. It's clear that the script isn't actually redefining the macro. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly what the warning says, you're redefining it. You defined it once on the command line, and again inside the file. If your intention is to _override_ it from the command line, surround the definition in your source within an `#ifndef NUMS` / `#endif` pair. As to _It's clear that the script isn't actually redefining the macro_ - you're right. The redefinition happened in your `#define NUMS 1` source. The command line was seen first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the macro on the command-line with `-DNUMS=100` you've provided a default value.

You're code is then overriding that default value when you do:

```
#define NUMS 1
```

The compiler warning is telling you exactly what has happened. Instead consider coding something like this:

```
#if !defined NUMS
#define NUMS 1
#endif
```

Now the compiler will only redefine `NUMS` as 1 when it hasn't already been defined (i.e. elsewhere in your source, or in this case the command-line.)